# Split method truncating result and appending '...' in the end

Tags: apex, string, split

```
String s = 'a b c d e f g h i j k l m';
System.debug(s.split(''));
```

above code returns `(, a,  , b,  , c,  , d,  , e, ...)`

am I missing something?
Please help

Comment: As per my understanding, you want to split the string by white space. But in split method you've mentioned '', which is different. Try s.split(' '). Also note that you cannot print the whole list in system.debug if the list is long enough. Try printing the list elements in for loop.

Answer (score 1):

I think its issue with logs which shows "..." after some text. Please try this:

```
String s = 'a b c d e f g h i j k l m';
for(String s1 : s.split(' ')){
    System.debug('value ' + s1);
}
```

Hope this will show you all values.